# Can having two Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate blocks in a same kotlin file cause any issue for executing 2 different tasks?

Tags: kotlin, scheduler

There are 2 Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate blocks in my kotlin project for 2 different tasks. I wanted to know if it may cause any issue or not. Because what I noticed is - both the tasks got executed twice in a single day and for another day they worked properly.

**Here's how the schedulers are coded to run at 11 AM IST -**

```
fun Application.configureScheduler() {
    val currentTime = LocalDateTime.now()
    var nextRunTime = currentTime.withHour(5).withMinute(30).withSecond(0)

    if (currentTime > nextRunTime) nextRunTime = nextRunTime.plusDays(1)
    val initialDelay = Duration.between(currentTime, nextRunTime).seconds

    Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask {
        runBlocking {
            try {
                log.info("Scheduler Executed")
            } catch (exception: Throwable) {
                log.error(
                    "Found Exception: $exception"
                )
            }}
    },initialDelay*1000L, TimeUnit.DAYS.toSeconds(1) * 1000L)


    Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask {
        runBlocking {
            try {
                log.info("Scheduler Executed")
            } catch (exception: Throwable) {
                log.error(
                    "Found Exception: $exception"
                )
            }}
    },initialDelay*1000L, TimeUnit.DAYS.toSeconds(1) * 1000L)
}
```

Seems like there's some kind of Unexpected behavior. Please share if you find the reason behind the issue, and how this should be properly coded. Thanks!